# Prove that $(1, 2, \ldots ,n)^{-1}=(n, \ldots, 2, 1)$ within the symmetric group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

Show that the cycles $(1, 2, \ldots, n)$, $(n,  \ldots, 2, 1)$ are inverse permutations.

Comment: Yes. And so can you if only you actually write up what everything means.

Comment: [Here's a mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) . Formatting your questions helps us to help you out and can rule out any ambiguities we face..

Comment: Umm sorry. You need to prove that inverse of permutation (1...n) is equal to  permutation (n...1). Is it better now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\sigma = (1, \ldots, n)$ and $\tau= (n , \ldots , 1)$. We need to show for every $k= 1, \ldots , n$ we have that
$$
\sigma(\tau(k)) = \tau(\sigma(k)) = k.
$$
If $k < n$ then $\tau(\sigma(k)) = \tau(k+1) = k$. If $k = n$ then $\tau(\sigma(n)) = \tau(1) = n$. An identical argument shows that $\sigma(\tau(k)) = k$, and we are done.

Comment: Oh, thank you soo much.

Comment: You can mark an answer as accepted via the tick on the left-hand side :)

Comment: Yeah, I see it now. Thank you, you helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that the inverse of your permutation $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 &\cdots& n \end{pmatrix}$ be $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 &\cdots& n \\ 
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 &\cdots& a_n\end{pmatrix},$ where $a_1,\, a_2,\, a_3,\ldots, a_n$ are to be determined. Since the composition is an identity permutation, so $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 &\cdots& n \end{pmatrix} \circ \begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 &\cdots& n \\ 
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 &\cdots& a_n\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 &\cdots& n \\ 
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 &\cdots& a_n\end{pmatrix} \circ \begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 &\cdots& n \end{pmatrix}=(1) \circ (2) \circ (3)\circ \cdots \circ (n).$

Now the only choice for the above equation to be true is $a_1=n,\, a_2=1,\,a_3=2,\,a_4=3,\ldots,a_n=n-1.$

Therefore the required inverse is $\begin{pmatrix}n & n-1 & n-2 & \cdots &1 \end{pmatrix}.$

Comment: Thank youu, both of these answers are very helpful to me.